# Move Diesel methods into other directories

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm following the Diesel examples guide, and my project looks exactly [like this](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/tree/master/examples/sqlite/getting_started_step_3). I want to change it so that instead of running `cargo run --bin publish_post 1`, you use `cargo run` and are presented with a loop prompting you for what action you want to run.

I've moved everything out of `bin/` and into the `controllers/` directory.  I want to reference this in `main.rs` as `use controllers::post`, so I have access to `post::delete()`, etc.

Once I move the files out of `bin/`, all the imports break. Likewise, I can't reference it from `lib.rs`.

Why do none of my imports work when the files are moved?  How I could access the methods from these files?

I want a structure like this:

```
├── controllers
│   └── posts.rs
├── lib.rs
├── main.rs
├── models.rs
├── schema.rs
```

And within `main.rs`, I want to be able to do something like:

```
use controllers::posts;

pub fn main() {
    // pseudocode
    loop {
        println!("what action would you like to perform?");
        let ans = capture_input();

        if ans == "insert" {
            posts::insert();
        } else if ans == "delete" {
            posts::delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a folder doesn't automatically make a Rust submodule. You need to do two things:

1. Declare the module explicitly in the crate root (`lib.rs` or `main.rs`):

   ```
   mod controllers;
   ```
2. Create `controllers/mod.rs` file and declare a submodule in it:

   ```
   mod posts;
   ```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you!